# MStest Vs JetBrain Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mstest, jetbrains-ide

What could be the reason that the same unit tests run successfully with jetbrains but not with mstest?

I am running unit test with jetbrains inside Visual Studio and every of them are success but, if a try to run them from command prompt with mstest, lots of them fails.

Thank you.

Comment: Configuration?  External dependencies?  Could be lots of things.